# How do i update my firebase v8 code to v9 in React-native?

Tags: firebase, react-native

So i want to set my documents on firebase in a way such that a submitted email  becomes the document ID
With v8 of Firebase i can do

```
db.collectiion('dbName')
.doc({authorizedUserEmail})
.set({
'myProperty: dataType'
})
```

But with v9 i cannot figure it out even while using the doc
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Also i'm writing React-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document), you can do as follows:

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

await setDoc(doc(db, "dbName", {authorizedUserEmail}), {
  'myProperty: dataType'
});
```

---

Note that "collection" takes only one "i" (your code contains `db.collectiion('dbName')`).

Comment: Thank you, The collection was a typo error during creation of question.